# How to redirect to appropriate route instead of URL::previous() after login

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I use `URL::previous()` to redirect the user to previous page he was there after login but I want to redirect him to appropriate route after login .Suppose a user wants to add a product his cart.but if he not logged in he has to login and after login i want to send him to cart page instead of product page he was there to add to cart. 
Is there any library like `URL::previous()` which will redirect the user after logged in which he needs to see ?

Comment: laravel has this support out of the box. just use the auth middleware. If a user tries to access a page he needs to login for, he gets redirected to a login-form and after he fills it . he gets redirected back to his previous location. Url::previous() is not necessary it will just remove the standard behavior

Answer (score 0):

In your login controller try to add this for example:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/cart';
```

Or if you want to add more logic you can use the method with the same name:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    // some logic

    return '/cart';
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to redirect to named route, you can modify your redirectTo method to use route() helper, and set 3rd to `false`:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return route(YOUR_ROUTE_NAME, [], false);
}
```

In this case route helper will return only URI path, not absolute URL.

Comment: Why can't I add `Redirect::route('home');` instead of `'/cart'`? How can I add a route name instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly handle this within the Route for  your cart, after you checked if the user is logged in you could take the `$request` object passed to your controller to get the requested URL and then pass this URL to your login page as an parameter.

```
//Controller

public function showCart(Request $request){
  // check if logged in
  if ($isLoggedIn){
    // Do stuff
  } else {
    $url = $request->path();
    return Redirect::route('/login', ['oldUrl' => $url]); // Pass the target url
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set auth middleware in to cart route. middleware check authentication and redirect on target page (for ex: cart) after login. if you use laravel 5.4. cart route should be like (for example) `Route::post('cart','cartController@cart')->middleware('auth')`